# Fetch and integrate Stripe Payment, but still on localhost

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am new in Web development, and now I got some obstacles bothering me a couple of days.
I am trying to integrate Stripe Payment into my APP. So my idea is having a button and call a function to checkout page with Stripe.

```
<button onClick = {() =>handleCheckout()}>
Payment
</button>
```

```
const handleCheckout = async () =>{
const response = await fetch('/checkout_sessions', {
mode: 'no-cors',
method: 'POST', 
header:{Accept: 'application/json', Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
})
```

And I have a checkout_sessions.js in another folder where I think it will link to Stripe Payment page, but I am still fetching on LocalHost which causing example **https://www.localhost:3000/www.stripe.com**
I have tried to link directly by the url example: (Link to='https://react.com/'>), but it doesn't work as well.

I think I might need to change a route setting or some, but I don't really know what next steps I can take.

Comment: which tech stack you are using  ?

Comment: What does `checkout_sessions.js` looks like? Is that file under the `/pages/api` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, creating a session must be done from the server side so you need to create a route inside the API folder in next.js.

```
// api/payment/session.js
import Stripe from "stripe";
import absoluteUrl from "next-absolute-url";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
if(req.method === "POST"){
  const {priceId , email} = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const {origin} = ablsouteUrl(req);
  // redirect user after payment done to your website id and you can check by having CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID
  let success_uri = `${origin}/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`;
 const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET, {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
  });
 const { id } = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    success_url: success_uri,
    cancel_url: origin,
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "subscription",
    customer_email: email,
    line_items: [{ price: String(priceId), quantity: 1 }],
  });
  res.status(200).json({ id: id });

 }
}
```

now from client you should send the priceId which comes from stripe and send it to the API body.

```
//Plans.js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const handleCheckout = async () => {
 const req = await fetch('/api/payment/session',{
 method : "POST",
 body : JSON.stringify({
    email : user_email,
    priceId : item_price_id
 })
});
const {id} = await req.json();
// client side stripe package!
   const stripe = await loadStripe(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHED
    );
  if (stripe) {
      // method which redirect user to stripe checkout page.
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: id, // id come from our api response
      });
    }
}
```

make sure you have installed Stripe, @stripe/stripe-js, and next-absolute-url for dynamic getting of the website domain if development it is same as origin of current running app.